# Kde plasma freezes unexpectedly

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde5

I have Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Last few weeks KDE started to 'freeze' occasionally.  Is this a known issue? Is there any way how I can gracefully close/restart just the UI from terminal?
But most important, what should I check to collect some usefull logs or details that could help to determine the cause of the problem?

Detailed description:
KDE just gets stuck and I can not do anything in the graphical UI. It seems that this usually happens when i switch desktops or even windows on the same desktop (but I cannot reproduce). I can move the mouse cursor, the music is still playing in the background (clementine - and I can control it via keyboards shortcuts), I can log in to the console using Ctrl+Alt+F1, I can log in via SSH... But I can not control KDE anymore - I can not move windows, switches desktops, close windows, opening apps or anyting similar. Once this happened during skype call and the call was not interrupted and i was able to communicate.
This started to happen only few weeks ago, it hasn't been happening before. I haven't installed any new hardware lately.

Technical details that might be relevant:

```
root:~# cat /etc/issue                                                                                                                  
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS \n \l
                                                                   
root:~# uname -a                                                                                                                        
Linux ryzen 5.19.0-32-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jan 30 17:03:34 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root:~#                                                                                                                                
root:~# kf5-config --version         
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'                                                                                                                                                                                                    
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Qt: 5.15.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
KDE Frameworks: 5.92.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
kf5-config: 1.0                                                                                                                        
root:~#                         
root:~# lshw -c display                                                                                                                 
  *-display                                                                                                                            
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0     
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c5      
       width: 64 bits                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb                                                       
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:144 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcd00000-fcd7ffff memory:c0000-dffff
root:~#                 
root:~# lshw -c processor                                                                                                               
  *-cpu                                                                                                                                
       description: CPU              
       product: AMD Ryzen 9 3950X 16-Core Processor
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
       physical id: 11    
       bus info: cpu@0      
       version: 23.113.0
       serial: Unknown  
       slot: AM4                
       size: 2199MHz 
       capacity: 4761MHz                                                                                                               
       width: 64 bits                                          
       clock: 100MHz         
       capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pc
lmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate
 ssbd mba ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdpru wbnoinvd arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale
 vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif v_spec_ctrl umip rdpid overflow_recov succor smca sev sev_es cpufreq
       configuration: cores=16 enabledcores=16 microcode=141561889 threads=32

root:~# lsmod | grep -i amd
edac_mce_amd           36864  0
kvm_amd               167936  0
kvm                  1130496  1 kvm_amd
ccp                   110592  1 kvm_amd
amdgpu              11300864  170
iommu_v2               24576  1 amdgpu
gpu_sched              49152  1 amdgpu
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 amdgpu
ttm                    98304  2 amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper
drm_display_helper    184320  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        200704  4 drm_display_helper,amdgpu
drm                   581632  22 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,drm_display_helper,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,ttm
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 igb,amdgpu
```

I have 128GB of memory overclocked to 3600MHZ (but i have it like this for 3 years without an issue). Also memtest seems ok (`memtester 1G 10`).

Thanks for any advice

Comment: It reads to me like KDE Plasma is still working, given what you said about `clementine` etc... however it maybe issues with your display driver? etc..   Have you switched to a text terminal and explored for clues?

Comment: `journalctl -p 3` might provide some clues.

Comment: Well, technically KDE Plasma might be still working but I think from any reasonable user perspective it's not. I just get the frozen image (with half 'shifted' desktops or during windows switching) and I can not use it in any useful way anymore. Might be that the issue is with display driver, but how can I check that?

Comment: ```journalctl -p 3``` shows few old errors with an old sata disk i'm using for backups. Nothing else. And this is not from the date when the issue happens.

Comment: Similar issue here, but in my case only mouse cursor keeps working, everything else does not. The issue started after upgrading from 20.04. I can change tty with Ctrl + alt + f3, but then I don't know how to fix tty1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by old MESA library.
I've updated the library and it fixed it.
For example this article describes how to do this (the one i used):
[linuxcapable.com/how-to-upgrade-mesa-drivers-on-ubuntu-linux](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-upgrade-mesa-drivers-on-ubuntu-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an issue with MESA 22.2.x.  It can be resolved by upgrading to MESA 22.3.0 or later.  See:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1463322/702934

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kwin/+bug/2018671

Comment: Ok, thanks. I upgraded Mesa and i'll see whether this is still happening. I'll let ou know if few days/weeks

Comment: so far i haven't experience this issue so it seems it helped. I've used this article: https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-upgrade-mesa-drivers-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Ubuntu has finally gotten around to addressing this with updated MESA packages on Ubuntu 22.04.  They're currently in the "testing" updates repository so you have to go out of your way to install them, but they could be released to mainline updates repo in the next week or so.  They have not created updated packages for Ubuntu 22.10 which may also suffer from this.

Comment: There is a fix out for Ubuntu 22.04 in the main repos now.  It doesn't look like they're going to fix 22.10; if you're on that release, upgrading to 23.04 will fix it.

Comment: @TruismsHounds do you know the exact version in the 22.04 main repos with the fix? I'm on 22.04 with no updates pending, have mesa 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1 but still hitting this issue.

Comment: Have managed to find that the fix will land in 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2 but this is not in jammy-updates yet, only in jammy-proposed. This comment on the launchpad bug suggests it's in -updates now https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/2003339/comments/72 but the package launchpad page disagrees, stating it's in -proposed https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2

Comment: There was a note this morning, it was in -updates for a bit but they pulled it because of another bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had this for a while on 22.04. The workaround was to leave a corner of a terminal visible at all times, and at freeze time click into it and issue `$ kwin --replace &`.

Upgrading to 23.04 fixed the crashes.